# Mobile / Tablet not allowing for scroll or menu on website

Tags: wordpress, mobile, responsive-design, tablet

I have this site: **http://362.a07.myftpupload.com/** The password is: **aynhoe_park**

For some reason when its viewed on a mobile or tablet, it won't allow me to scroll or to get the menu to work. Works perfectly on desktop, but ignores everything on mobile/tablet.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

worked out the problem, was a scroll function I had set up to force the site to scroll entire sections instead of a smooth scroll. Just set an if (is_mobile) funtion to hide it from mobiles/tablets.